# table gets moved between references and appendix

Tags: tables, floats, cross-referencing, appendix

I want to include a table right after a paragraph. I placed it after the text, but it gets moved down between the references and the appendix.
I tried to force the position using h! or H, but nothing worked. I noticed when I made another table it got moved down too but on another otherwise black page too. What could be the problem here?

```
\documentclass[man]{apa7}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

See table \ref{task}

\begin{table}[H]
\caption{\textit{Attribution of points}}
\begin{tabular}{lcc}
\hline
                              & A & B \\ \hline
1 & one point         & no point               \\
2 & no point          & one point              \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\label{task}
\end{table}
```

Comment: I suspect that there's not enough room left on the page to insert the table.  Since you specified `[H]`, you have forced it to be deferred until the end of the document.  Take a look at [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017) to learn how to handle the placement.

Comment: thanks for the reply! That does not seem to cause the problem though. No matter where I place the table in the code, it always ends up under the references. When I remove or change the [H] to something else, like [h!], nothing changes. When I change the documentclass to {article], it will be placed correctly, is it therefore a problem caused by that?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `apa7`, but suspect the page size is different from that of `article`.  Also, specifying only any "here" location guarantees that the float will be held to the end if there isn't enough room "here".  You really need to rethink.